# how to get a specific objects in an API?

Tags: python, api, dictionary

Hi i'm trying to consume an API in python, I made the connection and it works pretty well.
In that API I have 100 results, and I just want to get 10 of them, do you know how to do that?

```
import requests
import pprint

url='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/post'
response=requests.get(url)


pprint.pprint(response.json())
```

I tried with list comprehensions but I don't get how to use them in the dictionary for that API

Comment: You need to show an example of the JSON, and what you want to get out of it.

Comment: Consult documentation of your API to find if it has feature to limit number of entities fetched, so you can set it to 10

Comment: well that api just have a lot of objects with ids, names and titles I'm using it for practice. It doesn't have any documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make your request, if it was valid, the response object has a json method which returns the json data of your response.
In your case response.json() gives you a list of json objects.  You can manipulate that like any python list.

```
result = response.json()
first_ten = result[:10]
```

What the [:10] notation means is "Give me a piece of the list starting from zero up to 10".  The zero is implied because no first number is specified - it's the same as result[0:10] and you can use this notation to get any subsequence of the list you want.

P.S. Your url value is missing an s - 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/post', the right url is - 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'

Comment: when I try to use firts_ten=result[:10] my console shows me "NameError: name 'result' is not defined". I understand your point, you say when I have the json I use it as a list, right?

Comment: It is literally a list, so you can use it as one.  The url you gave returns a list of json objects.  When you call response.json() you get that list of json objects and you can manipulate it like any other list.